# Latest Rally release - portfolio attributes not able to be queried

Tags: sdk, rally

I have a custom application that uses the Cardboard object to display portfolio items. We had been using a custom attribute for Kanban state but in the latest release Rally added a standard attribute of a Portfolio Item called "State" which was basically doing what our custom attribute did. The problem is while the Cardboard object will take this attribute as the parameter to build the columns on it will never display any data. The columns all appear empty. I noticed this attribute is different then previous simple drop lists as it has two different options "Theme" and "Feature". Perhaps this works differently and Cardboard doesn't query correctly when passed this type of drop down??? Here is the simple version of the call:

```
        var dropdownAttribute = "State";
    if (stateDropdown !== null) {
        dropdownAttribute = stateDropdown.getValue();
    } 
    var cardboardConfig = {
         types: ["PortfolioItem", "HierarchicalRequirement", "Feature"],
         attribute: dropdownAttribute,
         fetch:"Name,FormattedID,Owner,ObjectID,ClassofService",
         query : fullQuery,
         cardRenderer: PriorityCardRenderer
    };

    if (cardboard) {
        cardboard.destroy();
    }
    cardboard = new rally.sdk.ui.CardBoard(cardboardConfig, rallyDataSource);
    cardboard.display(dojo.body());
```

Comment: Have you seen the new Portfolio Kanban Board? That is why we added our own State Field you may want to check it out. 

http://www.rallydev.com/productblog/2012/04/03/rally-portfolio-manager-there-is-more-than-one-way-to-look-at-it/

Answer (score 1):

The new State field is actually a reference to a new Domain Object. We added the object so that we could give each type of [Type](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/body.jsp#Type) of Portfolio Item different Kanban States.

What you are seeing is the complete list of all States for all types of Portfolio Item (Theme Feature).

If you want to recreate your current App you would need a new custom field on Portfolio Item and Hierarchical Requirement that has a name other than State. At this time Hierarchical Requirement does have a reference to the new State object but that is something we have plans to explore in the future.

Comment: So if I understand correctly State is an Object not an attribute and Hierarchical Requirement 'does not' reference this object so Cardboard control cannot use it as attribute to group columns by....Any idea when this will be fixed? Why switch to using Objects relating to objects verse simple attributes won't this break alot of your SDK??

Comment: We do have plans to add State as a solution to make ScheduleState customizable. I don't know when this work will be started though. Are you getting value from a single board that shows the progress of both Portfolio Items and Stories?

Comment: The cardboard is just showing portfolio items and I wanted to pass the new State as the attribute to group the columns by to the cardboard create but as you pointed out since its not a simple list attribute cardboard doesnt know what to do with it. So for now we are using a custom attribute on portfolio items for our own version of 'state' and I pass that to cardboard to create the columns to group by.